# Pulling back $\mathfrak g $-valued 1-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, fiber-bundles

Let $\omega$ be a vector-valued 1-form where the vector space is the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ and let $\mathcal P$ be a trivial principal bundle over a manifold $M$. Thus

$$
\omega\in\Omega^1(\mathcal P,\mathfrak g)=\Gamma((\mathcal P \times \mathfrak g)\otimes T^*\mathcal P).\tag1 
$$

I am reading that pulling back $\omega$ via the trivializing section $\sigma:M\to\mathcal P$ gives me a pull-back section $\sigma^*\omega\in\Omega^1(M,\mathfrak g)=\Gamma((M\times\mathfrak g)\otimes T^*M)$. Namely, $\sigma^*\omega$ is a smooth section of the bundle $(M\times\mathfrak g)\otimes T^*M$.

Since a pull-back section is a section in the pull-back bundle, namely

$$
\sigma^*\omega\in\Gamma(\sigma^*((\mathcal P\times\mathfrak g)\otimes T^*\mathcal P)),\tag2
$$

if what I am reading is correct, it follows that

$$
\sigma^*((\mathcal P\times\mathfrak g)\otimes T^*\mathcal P)\cong(M\times\mathfrak g)\otimes T^*M.
$$

Moreover, given a fiber bundle $\pi:E\to M$ and a function $f:M'\to M$, then the pull-back bundle $f^*E$ and the bundle $E$ share same fibers over points $x'\in M'$ and $x=f(x')\in M$, since it is a special case of a product bundle.

Then it follows that $(\mathcal P\times\mathfrak g)\otimes T^*\mathcal P$ must share same fibers with $(M\times\mathfrak g)\otimes T^*M$

$\textbf {Problem}$: same fibers means $\mathfrak g\otimes T^*P\cong\mathfrak g\otimes T^*M$, which is of course not true. So what's wrong?

Comment: Why is the sentence "It follows that ..." correct?

Comment: Because if I pull-back a section I obtain a section in the pull-back bundle. Then the paper says that the pull-back section $\sigma^*\omega\in\Omega^1(M,\mathfrak g)$ so it is a smooth section of $(M\times\mathfrak g)\otimes T^*M$. Then it follows what I wrote.

Comment: I do not think that the differential-geometric pullback of a form on $\mathcal P$ belongs to the pullback bundle. Think of a simpler case, without Lie algebras. The form $\omega\in\Gamma(T^*\mathcal P)$ is pulled back to $\sigma^*\omega\in\Gamma(T^* M)$ by a section, since $\sigma^*\omega(X)=\omega(\sigma_*X)$. But this pullback does not preserve the fibers: all forms on $\mathcal P$ that coincide on vectors tangent to the image of $\sigma$ are collapsed into the same form on $M$.

Comment: I see your point... well that's weird though!

The cotangent bundle is a vector bundle.
The pull-back of a section belongs to the pull-back bundle: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245965/pull-back-of-sections-of-vector-bundles.

But here that does not hold...

Comment: Another thing: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396928/a-fiber-product-is-a-fiber-bundle

Comment: Ok, it is a section of the pull-back bundle, but not a differential form.